# Orocos deployer as a ROS node

Tags: ros, orocos, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I would like to encapsulate an Orocos deployer into a ROS node. The deployer is an XML file that should be independant from the ROS files. I want to create a ROS node, load the XML file, and then run the node with minimal user implication (ideally the user should not notice that the node is a wrapper around Orocos).
I am looking for any ressource or example that could help me with that.
I am using the orocos_toolchain package in ROS.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/78791/orocos-deployer-as-a-ros-node/) by [Flavian](https://answers.ros.org/users/5572/flavian/) on ROS Answers with karma: 112 on 2013-09-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I posted this question on another forum and the answer is [here](http://www.orocos.org/forum/orocos/orocos-users/orocos-deployer-ros-node).

---

Originally posted by [Flavian](https://answers.ros.org/users/5572/flavian/) with karma: 112 on 2013-09-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0